# ImportError: cannot import name 'Conv2d' from 'network' (G:\Saadain\Anaconda\envs\SCALNet\lib\site-packages\network.py)

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to train a model and followed all the instruction but when I run this piece of code to train the model it throws an error

```
(SCALNet) C:\Users\Gigabyte pc\Desktop\COUNTING\SCALNet-main>python train.py --model DLANet --
dataset NWPU --batch_size 32 --loss LocLoss --gpus 0 --lr 0.0001 --epochs 20 --save_model_interval 2 --preload --save
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "train.py", line 12, in <module>
        from src.crowd_counting import CrowdCounter
      File "C:\Users\Gigabyte pc\Desktop\COUNTING\SCALNet-main\src\crowd_counting.py", line 8, in <module>
        from network import Conv2d, FC, Conv2d_dilated, np_to_variable
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Conv2d' from 'network' (G:\Saadain\Anaconda\envs\SCALNet\lib\site-packages\network.py)
```

Comment: Followed what instructions? Where did you get the code? It looks like it's trying to import things from an entirely wrong place (namely, your Anaconda env has a package called `network` it probably shouldn't.)

Comment: @AKX I have installed network, but still the error exists.    https://github.com/WangyiNTU/SCALNet

Comment: Yes, the issue likely is that you've installed a module called `network` that is not required.

Answer (score 0):

The repository, https://github.com/WangyiNTU/SCALNet, where this code is from, explicitly says it requires Python 2.7. I quote the "Requirements" section:

> Python 2.7

In Python 2.7, imports are resolved relative-first, i.e. when `src/crowd_counting.py` has `import network` in it, in Python 2 it means `import src.network as network`. In Python 3, it would mean importing the absolute name `network`, and that's what seems to be happening here.

You say you've installed `network` (likely because you got an error for it not being importable earlier, but that was a red herring).

What happens now on your Python 3 environment is that instead of an import error for `network` (which should be `src.network`), the program is trying to import unrelated things from an unrelated module, and doesn't work.

The takeaway is that you need to either

- use a Python 2.7 environment for this program and only install its requirements, or
- upgrade it to Python 3.x and proper Python 3.x imports (as illustrated above).

Comment: Still the error exists when I installed the python 3.7 again. But for the python 2.7 pip will not support as the life of python 2.7 has reached its end.

Comment: Yes, installing Python 3 won't help. You can use an older version of Pip (older than 20.0) with Python 2. But nonetheless, Python 2.7 is EOL.